# Drawing circles inside an axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

I'm trying to draw an uppersemicontinous function, And I would like to draw a filled circle at the top line and a empty circle at the bottom line.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}[compact=1.11]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=-2:2, samples = 100, color = blue!80!black] {x^2};
        \addplot[domain=2:6, samples = 100, color = blue!80!black] {-x^2+8*x-12};

        \filldraw[fill=blue!80!black,draw=blue!80!black] (2,4) circle(0.5);
        \filldraw[draw=blue!80!black,fill=white]  (2,0) circle(0.5);
\end{axis}
\filldraw[fill=blue!80!black,draw=blue!80!black] (2,4) circle(0.5);
\filldraw[draw=blue!80!black,fill=white]  (2,0) circle(0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This returns the image:
[image]

With the two small circles being placed wrong and wrong in size, and the big circles being placed wrong.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to use the axis coordinate system to place things onto your chart

Comment: Like this:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160331/15036

Comment: @Thruston This nearly works, the sizes are still off (they are sized as the small balls)

Comment: yes, I doubt that the sizes of the circles will use the axis coordinate system.  You will probably have to give them an absolute size.  But try looking in the documentation for a similar example.

Comment: Also relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45006/how-to-plot-intervals-and-points-in-the-real-line

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thruston I have found a size tat works, I just wondered if there was a smart way of doing it ;-). Will you answer the question so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up defining the coordinates within the axis environment and then drawing the stuff outside.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%[compact=1.11]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=-2:2, samples = 100, color = blue!80!black] {x^2};
        \addplot[domain=2:6, samples = 100, color = blue!80!black] {-x^2+8*x-12};
        \coordinate (center1) at (axis cs:2,4);
        \coordinate (center2) at (axis cs:2,0);
\end{axis}
\filldraw[fill=blue!80!black,draw=blue!80!black] (center1) circle(0.5);
\filldraw[draw=blue!80!black,fill=white]  (center2) circle(0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The size has to be adjusted, but I don't know which size you were after, you only wrote `0.5`.

**EDIT**: Here is the explanation why I decided to go this way. In more complicated scenarios, a circle may no longer be a circle if drawn in the axis environment. This happens for instance in 3D plots, consider e.g. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411899/121799): if one draws the duck there inside the axis, this will lead to something that makes one fear about the safety of the poor duck. Of course, there might be situations, in which one wants to have these deformations, or situations (like here) where it does not matter whether one draws the stuff inside or outside.

Answer (score 4):

one more example ... simple, concise and adjustable :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[samples=100]      
    \addplot[color=blue!80!black, domain=-2:2, 
             -{Circle[length=7mm, fill=blue]}] {x^2};
    \addplot[color=blue!80!black, domain= 2:6, 
             {Circle[length=7mm, fill=white]}-] {-x^2+8*x-12};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly simpler way to do what I think you were trying to do.  I expect that others more expert at PGFPlots than me can show something even simpler.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=blue!80!black, domain=-2:2, samples=100] {x^2};
    \addplot[color=blue!80!black, domain= 2:6, samples=100] {-x^2+8*x-12};
    \addplot[color=blue!80!black, only marks, style={mark=*, fill=blue!80!black}] coordinates {(2,4)};
    \addplot[color=blue!80!black, only marks, style={mark=*, fill=white}] coordinates {(2,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```